# Why is GDI+ cutting off scaled images?

Tags: c#, gdi+, image-manipulation

I am doing some image scaling using GDI+ (C#), and have noticed a problem where the image I am scaling is being cut off along the left and top edges.

http://zctut.com/cutoff.png

To reproduce this, create a new form project, save [this image](http://zctut.com/circle.png) into the bin\debug folder, and add the following code to the form (and, the corresponding events):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int scale = 1;
    Image img = Image.FromFile("circle.png");

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        //this makes the glitch easier to see
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

        RectangleF srcRect = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, img.Width, img.Height);
        RectangleF destRect = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, img.Width * scale, img.Height * scale);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        scale++;
        if (scale > 8) scale = 1;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the left- and top-most rows of pixels are being cut off, as if the scaling rectangle is starting half-way in the pixel.

Edit: For note, I also tried using a Scale transform instead of using rectangles as above, and it rendered exactly the same.

Now, that said, I did discover a work around. If you change the rectangle declarations in sample above like this:

```
RectangleF srcRect = new RectangleF(-0.5f, -0.5f, img.Width, img.Height);
```

So that we correct for the "half-way" thing, then the image renders correctly.

Basically, while this is easy to work around, am I doing something wrong, or is this normal behaviour?

Edit: As per Andrei Pana's suggestion, I tried adding this code before the drawing call:

```
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.None;
```

And, unfortunately, it did not affect the rendering. The edge was still cut off.

Comment: Does it also happen if instead of `RectangleF` you use `Rectangle`?

Comment: Try testing with a high-res image instead

Comment: @Lambert Originally, I was using `Rectangle`s, and had the same problem. I switched to `RectangleF` to get rid of having to cast all the time (since, sometimes I'm scaling images down too :) )

Comment: @Eric The actual images I am using are much larger. I actually only noticed the problem because I am drawing stuff on top of the image, and due to this problem, it is increasingly offset as the image zooms in.

Comment: People can see another sample code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776605/missing-half-of-first-pixel-column-after-a-graphics-transform-scale

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try setting the [PixelOffsetMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pixeloffsetmode.aspx) to PixelOffsetMode.Half. By default, for high speed anti aliasing, pixels are offset by -0.5

Comment: This sounds like it would be the answer, but (as I edited into my question), it doesn't affect anything...

Comment: I've run your code above and it works for me if I add this line: e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half; before drawing the image.

Comment: Oh, my answer was a little bit vague, I should have mentioned to use PixelOffsetMode.Half.

Comment: Ohh! I see. I've edited your answer to mention that specific fact, and accepted it.

Comment: Any idea why Default cuts half pixel and Half restores it? Ancient code error?

Comment: Okay for nearest neighbour interpolation mode, but for other modes now my image is cropped by half a pixel on all 4 sides.

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of the image to be 2 pixels larger (in each dimension) than the graphic that it contains.  I have encountered this as well, and have found that the antialiasing over-shoot is never more than 1 pixel on each side.

In other words, either turn off the anti-aliasing (which will fix this), or change this section of your code:

```
RectangleF destRect = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, img.Width * scale, img.Height * scale);
```

to this:

```
RectangleF destRect = new RectangleF(1f, 1f, img.Width * scale -2, img.Height * scale -2);
```

(or use an equivalent work-around that uses srcRect)

Yes, this is normal behavior and is a known issue with GDI+/.Net.

Comment: Actually, if I correct by 0.5f in each direction, and leave the width/height alone, it works fine (as I mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 0):

These are: my go-to setting for high quality and the one I've found works for pixelated images:

```
// High Quality
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

// Pixel Art
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```