# Missing half of first pixel column after a Graphics Transform Scale

Tags: c#, image, graphics, transformation

I have noticed that the half of the first pixel column of the image is not drawn after a Graphics Transform Scale on the OnPaint event.

All the code needed to reproduce it is at the end of the post. Basically I've created a Class derived from PictureBox called PictureBox2 and it overrides the OnPaint method to perform the Scale transformation. It also changes the InterpolationMode to NearestNeighbor to prevent Graphics from changing the pixels look.

The PictureBox control was added to a Form called Form6_GraphicsTest. The control is anchored in all sides. The PictureBox2 back color was changed to blue and the Form back color to dark grey.

**As you can see on the image below, only 1/2 of the first pixel column of the image is drawn. Why??** Am I missing something here??
[image: Missing 1/2 pixel Graphics bug]

Here is the original 10x10 8bpp image:
[image: 10x10 8bpp test image]

**EDIT - Solution**
For some **ODD** reason PixelOffsetMode.Default eats up 0.5 pixel. Solution: PixelOffsetMode.Half or HighQuality!

Code PictureBox2.cs

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GraphicsTest
{
    public class PictureBox2 : PictureBox
    {
        public PointF Zoom = new PointF(20, 20);
        private InterpolationMode interpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

        /// <summary>
        /// Paint the image
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The paint event</param>
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsDisposed)
                return;

            if (Image != null)
            {
                if (e.Graphics.InterpolationMode != interpolationMode)
                    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = interpolationMode;

                using (Matrix transform = e.Graphics.Transform)
                {
                    //e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

                    if (Zoom.X != 1.0 || Zoom.Y != 1.0)
                        transform.Scale(Zoom.X, Zoom.Y, MatrixOrder.Append);

                    //if (ImageDisplayLocation.X != 0 || ImageDisplayLocation.Y != 0) //Convert translation back to display pixel unit.
                    //    transform.Translate(ImageDisplayLocation.X / Zoom.X, ImageDisplayLocation.Y / Zoom.Y);

                    e.Graphics.Transform = transform;
                }
            }

            base.OnPaint(e);

            //If you want to draw something over the control in control coordinate, you must first reset the transformation! :D
            //e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
            //Draw your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Code Form6_GraphicsTest.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GraphicsTest
{
    public class Form6_GraphicsTest : Form
    {
        public Form6_GraphicsTest()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"D:\Test 10x10.8bpp.png");
        this.pictureBox21.Image = bmp;

        this.pictureBox21.Zoom = new PointF(20,20);

        this.ClientSize = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(this.pictureBox21.Zoom.X * bmp.Width) + 30, Convert.ToInt32(this.pictureBox21.Zoom.Y * bmp.Height) + 30);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.pictureBox21 = new GraphicsTest.PictureBox2();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox21)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox21
            // 
            this.pictureBox21.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.pictureBox21.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            this.pictureBox21.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.pictureBox21.Name = "pictureBox21";
            this.pictureBox21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 238);
            this.pictureBox21.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox21.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // Form6_GraphicsTest
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox21);
            this.Name = "Form6_GraphicsTest";
            this.Text = "Form6_GraphicsTest";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox21)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private PictureBox2 pictureBox21;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be related to [PixelOffsetMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pixeloffsetmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? This might be related to this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222774/bitmap-not-aligning-properly-in-panel). It has do with efficiency of rendering...

Comment: Yeap, I was just testing the guy solution and it works (before your post lol)! Thank you!

Comment: For some ODD reason PixelOffsetMode.Default eats up 0.5 pixel. Solution: PixelOffsetMode.Half or HighQuality.

Comment: Glad to hear this took care of it. This is definitely one of those graphics surprises, "What it doesn't draw my pixels like I told it too???"

Comment: PixelOffsetMode is where "graphics made up of square, hard edged, pixels" (like Lego blocks) starts to transistion to "graphics made up of square, soft edged, sampled colors (and alpha)." When you think of pixels as Lego blocks that are snapped down, defining scaling and blending is hard. Using pixels as samples, it's easier to define how to combine the background and foreground, and scale images to get the final display values.  But it means you have to work with the centers of the pixels (where the sample is taken) vs the edges of the pixels.